# how to add default value of category to a custom post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have one custom post in Wordpress, I want to add a default value to category (taxonomy of my custom post) When the user doesn't select any category while adding the post.

Please help me with this, the available answers do not help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you do exactly what you are looking to do: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189668/setting-default-category-for-custom-post-type-upon-autosave

Object Terms on Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

This solution will set the default category when they publish the post in the custom post type.

```
function save_book_meta( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    $slug = 'book'; //Slug of CPT

    // If this isn't a 'book' post, don't update it.
    if ( $slug != $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_set_object_terms( get_the_ID(), $term_id, $taxonomy );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_book_meta', 10, 3 );
```

In the future, please look through Stack Exchange and do extensive research before posting questions which already have thousands of answers to :)

Comment: Hii 
already looked into this but didn't work for me.
thanks!

Comment: @Anushree, that why you **have to** say in your question **exactly** what you tried and why it didn't work. So nobody wastes their time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code in functions.php make sure you change the custom-taxonomy with your custom taxonomy and value with the default category you want every post to save.

Not tested but this should work.

```
add_action('pre_post_update', 'saving_custom_single_post');
if( !function_exists('saving_custom_single_post') ){
    function saving_custom_single_post( $post_id ){
        if( get_post_type($post_id) == 'custom-post' ){
            $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'custom-taxonomy', array("fields" => "all"));
            if(empty($term_list)){
                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'custom-taxonomy', 'value', false );
            }
        }
    }
}
```